# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.el.ELResolver.invoke

Tags: jsf, weblogic, el

Im developing an application with JSF and Spring, based on a private framework. When I try to enter in my jsp and start to load some panelgrid from a bean I got this error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at javax.faces.component._ComponentAttributesMap.getComponentProperty(_ComponentAttributesMap.java:688)
at javax.faces.component._ComponentAttributesMap.get(_ComponentAttributesMap.java:322)
at org.richfaces.DataScrollerUtils.eval(DataScrollerUtils.java:86)
at org.richfaces.DataScrollerUtils.getRowCount(DataScrollerUtils.java:81)
at org.richfaces.event.DataTablePreRenderListener.processEvent(DataTablePreRenderListener.java:122)
at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:43)
at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl._traverseListenerList(ApplicationImpl.java:2471)
at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl.access$000(ApplicationImpl.java:120)
at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl$SystemListenerEntry.publish(ApplicationImpl.java:2662)
at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:601)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:580)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:517)
at org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlGridRendererBase.renderChildren(HtmlGridRendererBase.java:370)
at org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlGridRendererBase.encodeEnd(HtmlGridRendererBase.java:194)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:665)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:545)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:541)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:541)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:541)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1981)
at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:285)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:59)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:116)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:241)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:199)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:83)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at atlas.core.log.AtlasLogFilterRequest.doFilterInternal(AtlasLogFilterRequest.java:45)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at atlas.core.seguridad.AtlasAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AtlasAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:123)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at atlas.core.seguridad.x509.AtlasX509CaptureFilter.doFilterHttp(AtlasX509CaptureFilter.java:51)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:175)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)



Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.el.ELResolver.invoke(Ljavax/el/ELContext;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:111)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:163)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:219)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagValueExpression.getValue(ContextAwareTagValueExpression.java:96)
    at javax.faces.component._DeltaStateHelper.eval(_DeltaStateHelper.java:249)
    at org.richfaces.component.UISequence.getValue(UISequence.java:175)
    at org.richfaces.component.UISequence.createExtendedDataModel(UISequence.java:109)
    at org.richfaces.component.UIDataTableBase.createExtendedDataModel(UIDataTableBase.java:252)
    at org.richfaces.component.UIDataAdaptor.getExtendedDataModel(UIDataAdaptor.java:459)
    at org.richfaces.component.UIDataAdaptor.getRowCount(UIDataAdaptor.java:510)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.faces.component._ComponentAttributesMap.getComponentProperty(_ComponentAttributesMap.java:688)
    at javax.faces.component._ComponentAttributesMap.get(_ComponentAttributesMap.java:322)
    at org.richfaces.DataScrollerUtils.eval(DataScrollerUtils.java:86)
    at org.richfaces.DataScrollerUtils.getRowCount(DataScrollerUtils.java:81)
    at org.richfaces.event.DataTablePreRenderListener.processEvent(DataTablePreRenderListener.java:122)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:43)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl._traverseListenerList(ApplicationImpl.java:2471)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl.access$000(ApplicationImpl.java:120)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl$SystemListenerEntry.publish(ApplicationImpl.java:2662)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:601)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:580)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:517)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlGridRendererBase.renderChildren(HtmlGridRendererBase.java:370)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlGridRendererBase.encodeEnd(HtmlGridRendererBase.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:665)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:545)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:541)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:541)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1981)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:285)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:59)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:116)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:241)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:199)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at atlas.core.log.AtlasLogFilterRequest.doFilterInternal(AtlasLogFilterRequest.java:45)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at atlas.core.seguridad.AtlasAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AtlasAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:123)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at atlas.core.seguridad.x509.AtlasX509CaptureFilter.doFilterHttp(AtlasX509CaptureFilter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:175)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)
```

I'm using weblog 10.3.4 anda java 1.6. I have EL jars (el-api and el-impl) 2.2 in my /WEB-INF/lib.

Any idea?

Comment: WebLogic as being a true Java EE container already ships with EL out the box. What exactly is the reason you're bundling EL JARs in your webapp? It would only end up in collisions with WebLogic-bundled EL as you're currently facing. Are you after all trying to use the new EL 2.2 feature of invoking methods with arguments on an ancient Servlet 2.5 compatible container?

Comment: @BalusC adding <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes> to weblogic.xml may be a solution to override weblogic jars.

Comment: @erencan already had those labels earlier in my weblogic.xml but still not working

Comment: @BalusC I have the javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar in my web-inf/lib and with the tag prefer-web-inf-classes the server should use that version, right?

Comment: You should absolutely not have that JAR in your `/WEB-INF/lib`. Like as EL, the Servlet API/impl is supposed to be already provided by the target container itself.